# What is the best and easy to use graphics library available for C#?

Tags: c#, graphics

I need an open-source based graphics library to generate jpg graphics from database such as data from MS SQL server. I guess where the data coming from does not matter. The graphics will be something like trend for curve, bar, pie...

What I found are couple of libraries available such as NPLOT and ZedGraph, Before I roll my leef on those, just want to get guru's opinions on this issue. Any other libraries better than these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) are free but not open source. The data binding support appears to be [quite comprehensive](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx) and charts look quite nice as well.

My only experience with ZedGraph was from a couple of years back. It didn't play nice in our partial trust ASP.NET environments, so perhaps that's something to consider if you're attracted by it.

Kev

Comment: quick look at the page. It looks cool. Does it allow saving image as jpg? I need to run it as console app to auto generate jpg for html.

Comment: The Chart class has a SaveImage method and you can save to file/stream and a wide variety of formats including jpeg, gif, png.